# Where to store data about nested forms

Tags: reactjs

I have a form with nested items. So I would have a `List` and `Item`. `List`  has complete state about its items thanks to callbacks from item. Its manageable nesting, `List` knows what data to **submit**.

But what happens when I have a `ListOfList` (or a `ListOfListOfList`) which has a submit action that **submits the entire state**, of all lists and items contained therein? How do I update `ListOfList` of the entire state so that a submit action is possible?

I could call `List` when I create a new item, which then calls `ListOfList` which then calls setState. But this is callback hell.

---

Example data (can add/remove items, can create new/edit lists)

```
Agent: Alice

Handwash 10 *urgent
Bleach 5
Mop 2 *urgent


Agent: Bob

Handwash 2
Bleach 2
Mop 2 *urgent
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If a `ListOfList` renders a number of `List` components, and each `List` component renders a list of `Item` components and correctly updates its state and re-renders when an `Item` is added/removed, then no, `ListOfList` doesn't need to know about this. A child component can update without its parent having to know about this.

Comment: @HannesJohansson I have updated the question on why `ListOfList` needs to track the state: so that it can submit the entire stuff. It was a bad omission.

Comment: So your question is really about how a parent should get access to descendent components that it needs for some reason? Is that correctly interpreted?

Comment: @HannesJohansson you did! In this case its about forms.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation of React (or rather, React doesn't aim to solve that problem itself). First I'd recommend reading the following articles in the React docs: [communicate between components](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html) and [expose component functions](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/expose-component-functions.html).

As they say, for parent-child communication you can pass callbacks as props to the child component to be invoked whenever its state changes. In your particular case, `ListOfList` would pass a method to `List` as a prop that `List` calls whenever it updates, passing its up-to-date state as an argument (for example).

It would also be possible to expose a method in the child that returns its current state (although that feels very weird to me, but it's certainly possible), which can then be invoked by the parent via a `ref`.

For other component relationships, you can set up an event broadcast system, and Facebook themselves introduced the [Flux pattern](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) as one way of handling that.

I'd also recommend checking out their even newer proposal, [Relay](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/02/20/introducing-relay-and-graphql.html), which deals with data fetching and dependencies.