# What is the good way for child to parent communication using inverse data flow in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering something about the reverse data flow in a React app.
Considering this question: [data flow in react application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31566872/data-flow-in-react-application) and this article http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html

We can see that the "normal" way to communicate from child to parent component is using callback passing through this.props.myCallback. (the StackOverflow article is a good example)

My questions are:

- I understand the concept but what if we have deeper components? We would have to pass this callback to every component between the top parent component who hold the state and the actual triggering component. And if there is 3 to 4 components between them, I would have to pass the callback using this.props in each component.
- Why not using an Event Emitter? I could send an event from the deep child component and then listen to this event in my top state parent component. This way we could avoid all the code between these two.

Please tell me what are your thoughts about this!

Comment: I think this is where **[Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html)** comes into play. I know that we are just getting started with **React** itself and now we got to learn **Flux** too. But for the exact same scenario you just described, I find Flux complementing React very well. By the end of it, I see the data flowing in one direction. Here is a great learning resource I recently found to get started with Flux: **[Flux In Depth](http://blog.mgechev.com/2015/05/15/flux-in-depth-overview-components/)**.

Comment: and yes, Event Emitter is at play in Flux so there you go.

Comment: When I started using React, I quickly got to same situation.  I started using Flux, but was an overkill and a lot of verbose code.  I quickly found Reflux, and never looked back.  Definitely worth a look, you need to understand Flux, but deals with a lot of the leg work. Still uses stores, and has it's own mixins for example allowing the stores to have state. https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs

Comment: To extend my comment, the basic gist of reflux is to call actions that update the stores, the components listen for changes in the stores and propagate info use to change the state of children through the props. You only need to use callbacks where you're doing something specific with a parent component.

Comment: @sambomartin sounds good! this is exactly what I was expecting to do using an Event Emitter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35649635/communication-between-reactjs-components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learnt the hard way that it is a good practice to keep as much logic as possible in the highest level in the hierarchy of your components. Dan Abramov well expressed this idea in the article [Smart and Dumb Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0), where Smart Components are those that hold the logic, whereas Dumb Components are just meant to display.

So yes, the callback mechanism works well when you simply want to update the father's state, or you want the father to do an action whose logic you do not want to belong to the child.

When you have anything slightly more complicated than this I would suggest you go with a Flux-ish architecture of your taste. Flux indeed uses [node's EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) to communicate with the components.